# Laravel Eloquent Master Detail result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1
Just want to ask how to display ORM master detail when child return no data the the master data is not showing

This is My Master Model

```
<?php

namespace SpekWeb;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class ProdukGroup extends Model
    {
        public $table = 'product_group';
        public $primaryKey = 'prd_group';

        public function telcoProduct() {
            return $this->hasMany('SpekWeb\TelcoProduct', 'prd_group', 'prd_group');
        }
    }
```

Child Model

```
<?php

namespace SpekWeb;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TelcoProduct extends Model
{
    public $table = 'telco_product';
    public $primaryKey = 'tel_prd';
}
```

And this is My Controller

```
<?php

namespace SpekWeb\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SpekWeb\Http\Requests;
use SpekWeb\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use SpekWeb\ProdukGroup;
use SpekWeb\TelcoProduct;

class ProdukController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $memberPrices = ProdukGroup::with(array(
            'telcoProduct' => function($tpJoin) {
                $tpJoin->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
                $tpJoin->where('charge','>=',0);
                $tpJoin->whereMemType('1'); //variabel
                $tpJoin->where(function($qWhere) {
                    $qWhere->whereKodeKec('ASTAY'); //variabel
                    $qWhere->orWhereNull('cluster_gid');
                });
            },
            )
        )
        ->has('telcoProduct')
        ->get();
        return $memberPrices;
    }
}
```

I want the master record not showing when I filtered the code within 'with' area, using ->has('telcoProduct) still not working for me. The master record still showing on Blade Views.
Is there any trick to solve this problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `whereHas` function before your `with`. This is essentially like saying "if you have any, give me all records matching these criteria".

Your query should look like this (not tested).

```
public function index()
{
    $memberPrices = ProdukGroup::whereHas('telco_product', function($query) {
            $query->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
            $query->where('charge','>=',0);
            $query->whereMemType('1'); //variabel
            $query->where(function($qWhere) {
                $qWhere->whereKodeKec('ASTAY'); //variabel
                $qWhere->orWhereNull('cluster_gid');
            });
        },
        )
    )
    ->with(array(
        'telcoProduct' => function($tpJoin) {
            $tpJoin->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
            $tpJoin->where('charge','>=',0);
            $tpJoin->whereMemType(1); //this value replace by dynamic Input
            $tpJoin->where(function($qWhere) {
                $qWhere->whereKodeKec('ASTAY'); //this value replace by dynamic Input
                $qWhere->orWhereNull('cluster_gid');
            });
        },
    ))
    ->get();
    return $memberPrices;
}
```

Comment: Your modified query returns only ProdukGroup data. I want the $memberPrice returns its child record also.

Comment: See my updated post. `whereHas` only checks for specific criteria but doesn't eager load them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx @Tim

But when I using like you said with this code :

```
    $memberPrices = ProdukGroup::whereHas('telcoProduct', function($tpHas){
            $tpHas->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
            $tpHas->where('charge','>=',0);
            $tpHas->whereMemType(1); //this value replace by dynamic Input
            $tpHas->where(function($qWhere) {
                $qWhere->whereKodeKec('ASTAY'); //this value replace by dynamic Input
                $qWhere->orWhereNull('cluster_gid');
            });
        }
    )
    ->with(array(
        'telcoProduct' => function($tpJoin) {
            $tpJoin->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
        },
    ))
    ->has('telcoProduct')
    ->get();
    return $memberPrices;
```

I've got this result :

```
"prd_group": 1,
"grp_name": "Telkomsel",
"topup_code": "777",
"balance_code": "776",
"tel_id": 1,
"product_type": "reguler",
"with_code": 1,
"telco_product": [
    {
        "tel_prd": 4,
        "prd_group": 1,
        "prd_value": 5000,
        "stock": null,
        "keyword": "S5",
        "charge": 0,
        "price": 5000,
        "mem_type": 1,
        "prd_id": 4,
        "cluster_gid": null,
        "kode_kec": null
    },
    {
        "tel_prd": 4,
        "prd_group": 1,
        "prd_value": 5000,
        "stock": null,
        "keyword": "S5",
        "charge": 0,
        "price": 5100,
        "mem_type": 2,
        "prd_id": 4,
        "cluster_gid": null,
        "kode_kec": null
    },
]
```

Please check 2nd record of telco_product, it doesn't match the condition of query

> $tpHas->whereMemType(1);

Its display all the record inside telcoProduct join wd_productprice

I've try this code then :

```
    $memberPrices = ProdukGroup::whereHas('telcoProduct', function($tpHas){
            $tpHas->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
            $tpHas->where('charge','>=',0);
            $tpHas->whereMemType(1); //this value replace by dynamic Input
            $tpHas->where(function($qWhere) {
                $qWhere->whereKodeKec('ASTAY'); //this value replace by dynamic Input
                $qWhere->orWhereNull('cluster_gid');
            });
        }
    )
    ->with(array(
        'telcoProduct' => function($tpJoin) {
            $tpJoin->join('wd_productprice','telco_product.tel_prd','=','wd_productprice.tel_prd');
            $tpJoin->where('charge','>=',0);
            $tpJoin->whereMemType(1); //this value replace by dynamic Input
            $tpJoin->where(function($qWhere) {
                $qWhere->whereKodeKec('ASTAY'); //this value replace by dynamic Input
                $qWhere->orWhereNull('cluster_gid');
            });
        },
    ))
    ->has('telcoProduct')
    ->get();
    return $memberPrices;
```

And I've got the result as I expected

```
"prd_group": 1,
"grp_name": "Telkomsel",
"topup_code": "777",
"balance_code": "776",
"tel_id": 1,
"product_type": "reguler",
"with_code": 1,
"telco_product": [
    {
    "tel_prd": 4,
    "prd_group": 1,
    "prd_value": 5000,
    "stock": null,
    "keyword": "S5",
    "charge": 0,
    "price": 5000,
    "mem_type": 1,
    "prd_id": 4,
    "cluster_gid": null,
    "kode_kec": null
    },
    {
    "tel_prd": 4,
    "prd_group": 1,
    "prd_value": 5000,
    "stock": null,
    "keyword": "SS5",
    "charge": 0,
    "price": 5000,
    "mem_type": 1,
    "prd_id": 148,
    "cluster_gid": 3,
    "kode_kec": "ASTAY"
    }
]
```

Is My technique correct ? Should I write the condition twice on the query ?

Thx

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunately correct. The criteria are not shared and you therefore have to filter all parent objects out with `whereHas` and then load them with `with`. Thanks for pointing out the flaws in my code, I will update it.